# why can use class name as vector type?

Tags: java

```
class Buffer{
  .....
}
class K{
  Vector<Buffer> vec = new Vector<Buffer>();
  ...
}
```

In the general, vector type may be `int`, `float` or `String`.

why can use class as a vector type ? and what's mean ?

Comment: A Vector class is a one dimensional list of objects. It cannot contain basic types such as int or float. Please see the Java documentation.

Comment: This is not true: "In the general, vector type may be int, float or String." Where did you find the statement?

Comment: @fdreger I think. Because I have never used class types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> why can use class as a vector type ? and what's mean ?

If you want to store instances of class `Buffer` in a `Vector` than the generic type argument that you will need to pass to `Vector` will be `Buffer`

```
Vector<Buffer> vec = new Vector<>();
```

above vector will only contain instances of `Buffer` class and if you try to add any thing else other than the instance of `Buffer` class in this `Vector`, you will get an error.

Comment: To put it very concise, you can read `Vector<Buffer>` as "a vector of buffers", or `List<String>` as "a list of strings", et cetera. The technical term for this is "Generic types".

Comment: so vec can use/store all member data and Method from ```class Buffer```?

Comment: @Itati `vec` will store only `Buffer` class instances/objects if declared as `Vector<Buffer> vec = new Vector<>();`. It will grow in size as you add more instances of `Buffer` class in it.

Comment: Of course, I don't think that there's any good reason to be using Vector in 2020. You should use ArrayList instead. Vector is a vestige of Java 1. Its should be deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

The Vector class contains objects only;cannat contain primitive data types.İt is also possible to directly access any element of a vector.Vector is essentially an array.The important difference from the array is that its lenght can be changed.
[enter link description here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)

Can you check this link you will see detail desciption